# How to express the integral $\int_0^a\frac{\sin x}{x} dx$ using other integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

For $a >0$, I need to express the integral $$\int_0^a \frac{\sin x} x \, dx$$ according to the following integrals:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-ay}}{1+y^2} \,dy ~~~\text{ and }~~~~ \int_0^\infty \frac{ye^{-ay}}{1+y^2} \,dx .$$

I know that $\int_0^a \frac{\sin x}{x} \,dx $ is the sine integral equals $\operatorname{si}(a)$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ when $a \rightarrow \infty$, but how to express the integral according to the other integrals?

Comment: Do you want to show that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{sinx}{x} = \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: @EugeneSirkiza no ! I need to express the integral $\int_0^a \frac{\sin x}{x} dx$ using the other integrals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes it is useful to recall that
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-xy} \, dy = \frac 1 x \quad \text{if } x>0.
$$
$$
{}
$$
\begin{align}
& \int_0^a \frac{\sin x} x \, dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^a \left( \int_0^\infty e^{-yx} \, dy  \right) \sin x \, dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^\infty \left( \int_0^a e^{-yx} \sin x \, dx \right) \, dy. \tag 1
\end{align}
Line $(1)$ is valid because
\begin{align}
& \iint\limits_{(0,a)\times(0,\infty)} \left| e^{-yx} \sin x \right| \, d(x,y) \\[10pt]
\le {} & \iint\limits_{(0,a)\times(0,\infty)} e^{-yx} \, d(x,y) = \frac a x < +\infty.
\end{align}
Now start with line $(1)$ and integrate by parts twice, getting
\begin{align}
& \text{integral} \\[8pt]
= {} & (\text{some expression}) + \Big(\text{something} \times \text{same integral}\Big)
\end{align}
and do a bit of algebra to get
\begin{align}
& \int_0^a e^{-yx} \sin x \, dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{1 - (\cos a)e^{-ya} - y(\sin a) e^{-ya}}{1+y^2}.
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{align}
& \int_0^a \frac{\sin x} x \, dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^\infty \frac{1 - (\cos a)e^{-ya} - y(\sin a) e^{-ya}}{1+y^2} \, dy \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac \pi 2 - (\cos a)\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-ya}}{1+y^2} \, dy - (\sin a) \int_0^\infty \frac{ye^{-ya}}{1+y^2} \, dy.
\end{align}

Comment: Many Many thanks. A technical question: is it necessary to validate step $1$ as you did "Fubini's theorem". Can't we simply use "Tonelli's theorem" to switch th order of integration since we have a non-negative function?

Comment: @user008 : We could do that if it were a non-negative function. Thus if $a$ is small enough, it works. I'm anticipating that you may want to take the limit as $a\to\infty$ of the last expression in this posted answer. (And note that you can "accept" this answer.)

Comment: We know  $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$$ But, according to last result, when $a \rightarrow \infty$ it is not $ \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: @user008 : How so? Both integrals approach $0,$ leaving $\pi/2. \qquad$

Comment: @user008 : Here a question arises: $$ \lim_{a\,\to\,+\infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{ye^{-ya}}{1+y^2} \, dy = \int_0^\infty \lim_{a\,\to\,+\infty} \frac{ye^{-ya}}{1+y^2} \, dy \quad \text{?} $$ The dominated convergence theorem entails that these are equal if there is some function $g$ (not depending on $a$) such that for all sufficiently large values of $a$ we have $$ \left| \frac{ye^{-ya}}{1+y^2} \right| \le g(y) $$ and $\int_0^\infty g(y)\, dy<+\infty.$ I think you can fairly easily find such a function. $\qquad$